# How to mute a tab in Safari when it isn't playing audio?

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

The "Mute this tab" menu item is greyed-out on http://www.donttap.com

I think that's bc the tab doesn't play audio except in the moment you click a tile.

But I don't want it to make noise when I click a tile *later*.

How can I pre-emptively mute tabs that I know will be noisy in Safari?

Comment: No easy way to do this... You need to make it play audio (click a tile) and quickly mute the tab. Or you can use the developer console to make it play a sound programmatically then mute it, but I don't know how far you're willing to go.

Comment: Almost agreeing with @user3052786, Would stopping autoplay work on Audio?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii No, preventing autoplay does just that, it doesn't stop media playback initiated by user interaction as in this case